# How to get back to original view using CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

how can I set the default view again after applying filter to my observable collection.
I apply filter like this and it filters the view as per my delegate logic but at some point I want the original list in the view.How to do it?

```
  ICollectionView collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myList);
            collectionView.Filter = mydelegate;
```

Comment: `collectionView.Filter = null;`

Comment: Have you seen  [WPF ICollectionView Filter Reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520653/wpf-icollectionview-filter-reset)?